# Why memory leak is not reported when perl is compiled with `DEBUG_LEAKING_SCALARS`?

Tags: perl, debugging, memory-leaks

I compile perl with `DEBUG_LEAKING_SCALARS` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736961/how-to-compile-perl-with-debug-leaking-scalars)

**CASE 1**
I follow this [DOC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlhacktips.html#PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL) to test memory leaking reporting:

```
env PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL=2 valgrind perl -e '@x; $x[0]=\@x'
==7216== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7216== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7216== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7216== Command: perl -e @x;\ $x[0]=\\@x
==7216== 
==7216== 
==7216== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7216==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7216==   total heap usage: 1,310 allocs, 1,310 frees, 171,397 bytes allocated
==7216== 
==7216== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7216== 
==7216== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7216== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Nothing is reported.**

**CASE 2**
I even in my XS sub do [this thing](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2006/03/msg110535.html). Exactly:

```
#define PERL_NO_GET_CONTEXT
#include "EXTERN.h"
#include "perl.h"
#include "XSUB.h"

#include "XSUtils.h"
#include "ppport.h"

void
call_perl() {
    SV *sv;
    sv =  sv_2mortal( newSVpv( "XS::Utils::hello", 0 ) );

    newSViv( 323 );     //<<<< SHOULD LEAK
    printf( "Hi 3\n" );

    ENTERSCOPE;
    CALLPERL( sv , G_DISCARD|G_NOARGS );
    LEAVESCOPE;
}

MODULE = XS::Utils                    PACKAGE = XS::Utils

void
test()
    CODE:
        call_perl();
```

[Link to the REPO](https://github.com/KES777/XS-Utils)

```
$ env PERL_DESTRUCT_LEVEL=2 valgrind perl -Iblib/arch/ -Iblib/lib -MXS::Utils -e 'XS::Utils::test()' 
==7308== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7308== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7308== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7308== Command: perl -Iblib/arch/ -Iblib/lib -MXS::Utils -e XS::Utils::test()
==7308== 
Hi 3
Hello
==7308== 
==7308== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7308==     in use at exit: 1,502 bytes in 5 blocks
==7308==   total heap usage: 12,876 allocs, 12,871 frees, 1,945,298 bytes allocated
==7308== 
==7308== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7308==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7308==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7308==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7308==    still reachable: 1,502 bytes in 5 blocks
==7308==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7308== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==7308== 
==7308== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7308== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Nothing is reported too**

**CASE 3**
I fix module [Devel::LeakTrace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::LeakTrace) (The [FIX](https://github.com/KES777/Devel-LeakTrace)):

```
$ perl -MDevel::LeakTrace -Iblib/arch/ -Iblib/lib -MXS::Utils -e 'XS::Utils::test()' 
Hi 3
Hello
```

**Nothing is reported too**

**CASE 4**
I only found [Test::LeakTrace](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::LeakTrace) do its job:

```
$ perl -MTest::LeakTrace::Script=-verbose -Iblib/arch/ -Iblib/lib -MXS::Utils -e 'XS::Utils::test()' 
Hi 3
Hello
leaked SCALAR(0x208e1c0) from -e line 1.
ALLOCATED at -e:1 by entersub (parent 0x0); serial 9642
SV = IV(0x208e1b0) at 0x208e1c0
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
  IV = 323
```

**Why built in tool in perl report nothing about leaking?**
What did I wrong? How to debug leaking memory with `DEBUG_LEAKING_SCALARS` tool?

Comment: You know, maybe you should just hang out in #p5p on irc.perl.org. I have the feeling the people there are a bit more versed with this stuff you're doing than we are here. :)

Comment: @simbabque .., but for a reference would be nice to know the answer too... :) :)

Comment: @jm666 absolutely. It's super useful of him doing that, but he ends ups posting his own answer after a day or two every time. With a bit of context about what he's doing it could be a tech blog. :D Please continue Eugen.

Comment: @simbabque Your upvotes gives me the energy! =)

Comment: Ok, convinced. Here, have it. :P

Answer (score 1):

Actually not an answer, but from *Dave Mitchell*:

> The main purpose of DEBUG_LEAKING_SCALARS isn't to list leaked scalars
>   (!!)
>   It's to help in tracking down things generally related to leaked scalars
>   and refcount problems. its two main features are that it turns SV
>   allocation from being a macro to being a function so that you can easy
>   attach a breakpoint; and that it adds instrumentation to each SV showing
>   where it was allocated (as displayed by Devel::Peek).

But I will not know what to debug, because I do not know that something is leaking. Like **CASE from 1 to 3** described above. I was sure that:

```
newSViv( 323 );
```

Did not leak.

So `DEBUG_LEAKING_SCALARS` **should list leaked scalars**

Also I have found this comment at perl commit history:

> -[ 24088] By: davem                on 2005/03/28  21:38:44
>   -   Log: expand -DDEBUG_LEAKING_SCALARS to instrument the creation of each SV

This will be very useful for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434132/how-to-tie-every-variable-in-perl-script) task to my mind.

Comment: This answers why the `DEBUG_LEAKING_SCALARS` doesn't list leaks (cause it's point is to make debugging leaks easier, not to identify leaks in the first place), but it makes the dubious and unexplained claim that `DEBUG_LEAKING_SCALARS` should list leaked scalars, and it doesn't explain why the tools that are designed to find leaks (`valgrind` and Devel::LeakTrace) don't find it.